# PHP Allow only one line who contains a specific value in a sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm searching for a better solution to my problem.

My array looks like this and is sorted by releaseDate :

```
array:12 [
    0 => array:3 [
        "id" => "11602"
        "released" => false
        "releaseDate" => "2015-09-09"
    ],
    1 => array:3 [
        "id" => "11601"
        "released" => false
        "releaseDate" => "2015-08-25"
    ],
    2 => array:3 [
        "id" => "11600"
        "released" => true
        "releaseDate" => "2015-08-25"
    ],
    ...
]
```

I want to keep only the closest to release line ("released" => false) and remove the others.

My current solution is :

```
private function keepOneVersionUnreleased(array $array)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ((isset($array[$i+1])) && ($array[$i]['released'] === false) && ($array[$i+1]['released'] === false)) {
            unset($array[$i]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Does somebody have a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php). It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as

```
$result = array_filter($your_array,function($v){ return ($v['released'] === false);});
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/424114)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value)
 {
     if ((isset($array[$key+1)) && ($array[$key]['released'] === false && ($array[$key+1]['released'] === false)){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
 }
return $array;
```